# Rewrite rules - page does not exist

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've made a website for a client for a driver school, and we need to use special plugins connected to a company that handles the database.

So from the website, we connect to their database, and load all the different products/packages customers can buy.

The issue is when i've entered lets say example.com/webshop and go to category "theory" the url is in this example.com/webshop/theory.

This url work when you first go to webshop -> theory

But if you try to reload when you are at webshop/theory you get an error that the page doesnt exist.

Seems to be a rewrite rule thats not working, any suggestions from the experts in this group?

Comment: You will probably need to hire someone who can access the servers directly to find out what is going on. This is one of those problems where it could be multiple things, and a general description of what's happening isn't enough to give a clear answer as to what is causing it.

Comment: Is it a custom website or some cms? Is the 404 error only happens at pages where that external database/plugin needs to do any task? What server you are on? (if Apache, can you check .htaccess file? Or you may check the requests from some server request log or any error log (if these accessible on your host) for more information maybe? Http request/response headers etc. All might be useful information to narrow on the problem.